# I cant retrieve any data from Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to retrieve data from firestore using FutureBuilder and ListView.builder();
Here's is my code;

CollectionReference

```
  CollectionReference firestoreref = Firestore.instance.collection("business");
```

And here's my reference;

```
          FutureBuilder(
            future: firestoreref.getDocuments(),
            // ignore: missing_return
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
                  ),
                );
              }
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                Center(
                  child: Text("Waiting...'"),
                );
              }
              // Collection Data ready to display
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                // print(widget.shopname);
                // Display the data inside a list view
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: snapshot.data.data[index]["name"],
                    );
                  },
                );
              }

              // Loading State

              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              );
            },
            )
```

I can't get what's wrong.Kindly Help.

Comment: Since the function does not async.

Comment: Try calling `.get()` instead of `.getDocuments()`.